# Django allow user to edit their profile

Tags: django, edit

How do I make a function that allows user to edit their own profile?

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_user(request):
    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
        userId = request.session['_auth_user_id']
        userDetails = User.objects.get(pk=userId)
       if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            userDetails.first_name = request.POST['firstname']
            userDetails.last_name = request.POST['lastname']
            userDetails.email = request.POST['email']
            userDetails.zip = request.POST['zip']
            if form.is_valid():
                userDetails.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/edit_user/')
        else:
            form = UserProfileForm()

    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response('edit_user.html',variables,)
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=254)
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=20)
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=20)
    zip = forms.CharField(label='Zipcode', max_length=5)
```

edit_user.html

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/edit_user/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Save Edits</button>
                        </form>
```

It will not display the fields, it shows blank: 
http://gyazo.com/48ee38b22434aae418cfe61accb00bd8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `login(request, user)` you can access the User info from `_auth_user_id` in session like
`request.session[_auth_user_id]` . So you can make a function like edit profile

```
def edit_profile(request):
    template_var = {}
    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
        userId = request.session['_auth_user_id']
        new_profile_user = Profile.objects.get(user_id=userId)
        userDetails = User.objects.get(pk=userId)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            userDetails.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            userDetails.email = request.POST['email']
            userDetails.save()
     template_var['new_profile_user']=new_profile_user
     return render_to_response('edit_user.html',template_var,)
```

Now in your template do like {{ new_profile_user.first_name }}

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Please see my edited post, it won't display any field forms. Thanks.

Comment: @user4234041 include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` this also in <form tag .. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Comment: And your `render_to_response` doesn't have `form` dict .. You got it ?

Comment: I got it now, I forgot to include form dict, thanks for the heads up. I have another question, how would I display the user's info (before user wants to make any changes)? Thanks.

Comment: oh .. ! my ans crct then give me tick mark ya .. I will help you surely ... :)

Comment: Okay, I marked your answer. So how would I display the user's info (before user wants to make any changes)?

Comment: Yes, display user info in a textbox, so that allows user to see what is their current information before making any changes.

Comment: have any doubt ? I modified my answer

Comment: Sorry for long delay, it shows that Profile does not exist.

Comment: @user4234041 Did you read django's default User model ???? ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#user )

Comment: If you want more field other than default. Then you have to declare your own User model( like i did in profile ) . A many-to-one relationship. Means Many profile field can related with User model..

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
    def profile_edit(request, template_name='profile_edit.html'):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_profile = form.save(commit=False)
        user_profile.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, template_name,{'form': form})
```